# How can I search for a directory only under a specified directory and nowhere else?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, windows-desktop-search

My laptop has two drives, my regular hard drive and a smaller SSD.

Somewhere on my computer is a folder that is just called “R” that contains code I have was working on a few weeks ago. I can not find it. Searching just on R turns up hundreds of directories containing the letter R. Search on R followed by a space returns dozens of directories called R,  nearly all of them in a program files directory. They do not include the R directory I am seeking. How can I search for a directory called R, without more to the name, in locations that exclude “program files”?

Comment: I would recommend powergrep, but give searching for `="R"` a try. Google `file explorer search wildcards` for more info

Comment: In the **Explorer** search box: `kind:Directory name:="R" NOT folderPath:~"*Program Files*"` (not at PC to test, unsure about NOT preceding folderPath... )

Comment: @KeithMiller, close:  `kind:folder AND filename:"R"`  No need to exclude *Program Files* or x86 folders. The quotes exclude folders with *R* as *part* of the name.

Comment: Actually, `name:"R"` will also return names such as `R squared` or `Two Pi R`, `name:="R"` limits the return to only items named "R".